# DNS resolve failing for unknown reason

Tags: kali-linux, dns, wget

I get the following error while installing jdk 8 in my 64-bit kali linux.

```
root@kali:~# apt-get install oracle-java8-installer 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
oracle-java8-installer is already the newest version (8u111+8u111arm-1~webupd8~0).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  aapt android-libaapt android-libandroidfw android-libbacktrace android-libbase
  android-libcutils android-liblog android-libunwind android-libutils android-libziparchive
  fastjar fonts-dejavu-extra jarwrapper java-wrappers junit libadns1 libantlr-java
  libantlr3-runtime-java libapache-pom-java libatinject-jsr330-api-java libatk-wrapper-java
  libatk-wrapper-java-jni libcommons-cli-java libcommons-io-java libcommons-lang3-java
  libcommons-parent-java libcrypto++6 libguava-java libice-dev libjaxp1.3-java libjsr305-java
  libpthread-stubs0-dev libsm-dev libsmali-java libstringtemplate-java libx11-dev libx11-doc
  libxau-dev libxcb1-dev libxdmcp-dev libxmlunit-java libxpp3-java libxt-dev
  libyaml-snake-java python-adns python-easygui python-levenshtein python-metaconfig
  python-pycryptopp python-pysnmp4 python-pysnmp4-apps python-pysnmp4-mibs smitools
  x11proto-core-dev x11proto-input-dev x11proto-kb-dev xorg-sgml-doctools xtrans-dev
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1463 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up oracle-java8-installer (8u111+8u111arm-1~webupd8~0) ...
Using wget settings from /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer/wgetrc
Downloading Oracle Java 8...
--2016-12-16 21:05:09--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u111-b14/jdk-8u111-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving false (false)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘false’
download failed
Oracle JDK 8 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java8-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have searched a lot about this but couldn't figure out what's causing it.

If I run `wget http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u111-b14/jdk-8u111-linux-x64.tar.gz` it works fine.

Also `nslookup google.com` and `ping google.com` works without error.

Also I deleted everything that was there in the file `/var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer/wgetrc` but again the same problem.

Please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's peculiar issue.

DNS is not failing for some strange reason, your DNS is working fine. However the package you're attempting seems with a broken post-install script, which is taking "false" as a hostname and passing this to wget, instead of the expected hostname.

It is pretty obvious from the output:

> ...
>
> --2016-12-16 21:05:09--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u111-b14/jdk-8u111-linux-x64.tar.gz
>
> Resolving false (false)... failed: Name or service not known.
>
> wget: unable to resolve host address ‘false’

If I wanted to dig deeper into it, I'd have a look in /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer/wgetrc to see if there is something broken there, also `apt-get clean` and retry.

I would suggest you to try achieving this result - installing java with alternative method, e.g. described here http://www.2daygeek.com/install-oracle-java-using-java-alternatives-method-on-ubuntu-centos-debian-fedora-mint-rhel-opensuse/ and see if it works out for you - probably this will be the fastest.

Comment: I don't know if its relevant but here's another piece of information. Earlier I was getting "hostname can not be blank" error in java while downloading a package using eclipse. So, I uninstalled java and now installing java again.

Comment: I managed to pull the post install script. Here it is https://gist.github.com/lokeshh/de38793c7fa9fe3955f299d0c173fdb3

Comment: This issue is resolved but still my eclipse issue isn't resolved yet. @Niklai do you mind taking a look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41164387/internal-error-while-installing-eclipse-neon)

Answer (score 3):

I've figured out the problem after going through the post install script. The problem was in `/etc/apt/apt.conf`. It was miss-configured as `Acquire::http::Proxy "false"`. This worked for `apt` but other programs like this script weren't able to work because of this. I remove this line and now the problem is gone.

Thanks @Nikolai for the suggestion about the post install script.

Comment: Glad to see you've resolved it.

Comment: Thanks! I had a really old /etc/apt/apt.conf last modified Aug 2006 (lots of Ubuntu updates after another...), after removing it I can finally update the Oracle JDK automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Add "use_proxy=no" in /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer/wgetrc and re-try the below command:
apt-get install oracle-java8-installer

For me, it worked.